# How to have latest UI components in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I noticed that with every iteration of the Android platform, the buttons and UI components keep looking slicker and slicker. 
Besides API changes I want to be able to adopt the latest buttons (such as spinners with the bottom-right corner as an arrow), or Jelly bean icons, across all versions of Android where my application is used. How is this usually accomplished?

Comment: You shouldn't do that, you should use the UI components of the version the application is running at to preserve the _look & feel_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to adopt the latest buttons across all versions of Android where my application is used.

The [Holo Everywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere#readme) library is a popular choice to do this.

Comment: I'm in two minds about this. In some ways I agree with K-ballo because I want my apps on a particular device and Android version to look the same as the other apps (preserving look and feel). On the other hand, if a user of my apps has more than one device with different Android versions, I can see the advantage of unified UIs. Hmmm.